# Allow button to be used multiple times in one activity

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a calculator button (=). When I click it the first time, it works great. When I click it subsequent times, it fails - does not update the TextViews on subsequent clicks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button viewCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    final TextView viewTimeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTimeRemaining);
    final TextView viewTimeSaved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTimeSaved);

    final TextView viewMinimumPayment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editMinimumPayment);

    viewCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        viewMinimumPayment.setText("" + minPayment);
        viewTimeRemaining.setText("" + nStarting);
        viewTimeSaved.setText("" + nDifference);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I took out a lot of irreverent stuff so if it doesn't look like it does anything, it does...

When I click the button it should override the 3 textviews with the updated calculations. When I test it, I am changing the variables in drastic ways so there is a mathematical change.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: nothing changes on subsequent button clicks - updated above

Comment: To debug this, I would suggest putting a log inside the onclick method, to see if it is called everytime, and to check the values of the minPayment, nStarting and nDifference variables.

Comment: Maybe some of the 'irrelevant' stuff you took out is relevant! :)

Comment: Thanks for the debug idea, I'll work on that for a while.. theoretically, the onclick should be called each time it's used without refreshing the activity correct?

Comment: Yes, button should be re-clickable. Could it be that it is actually working but the values of  minPayment, nStarting and nDifference have not changed so you do not see a difference? Try to put a Toast in the onClick to see if the flow reaches there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u have defined the calculation (minPayment and so) in onCreate method. So they are not getting updated. Try to put those calculation inside onclick method so that they are updated. Can you post the entire code or a part of code showing where minPayment is updated.